# Scene doesn't fit to the screen

Tags: unity-game-engine

I am developing a game for Android by Unity. I have a scene consisting of a map as you can see from the screenshot of Unity Editor. When i play in the editor, the scene perfectly fits to the screen. However, when i run the game in my phone, there remains a vertical space out of the map and it doesn't completely fit.

I am using "Scale With Screen Size" and the reference size is my phone's size which is 1080 by 1920. I leave the screenshot of the editor and my phone during the play mode.

What might be the possible reason for this problem? Thanks in advance..

### Screenshot from the editor

[image: This is from the editor]

### Screenshot from the Phone

[image: This is from the phone]

Comment: What happens if you maximize the editor screen?

Comment: @Doh09 i haven't tried it but do you think that it will work?  There shouldn't be any problem with editor in my opinion as the scene is rendered correctly...

Comment: I mention trying it as sometimes I experience that it looks differently in maximized view in the editor when you have the editors perspective set to "free aspect" which you have. You can set it e.g. to 16:9 aspect ratio if you want it fixed.

Comment: Oh yeah! The problem was what you mentioned. It works now.. Thanks a lot!